# Find generic equation (closed form) for polynom coefficient

Tags: real-analysis

I have a series of equations for the coefficients of a polynom. For every order of the coefficient there are more terms. I'm trying to write this in a closed form for any coefficient, but I'm stuck on how to do this. Here is what I have so far:

$$
    s^1:
        \sum_{i = 1}^{N}
        \sum_{j = i}^{N}
        R_i \cdot C_j$$

$$
    s^2:
        \sum_{i = 1}^{N - 1}
        \sum_{j = i}^{N}
        \sum_{k = i}^{j - 1}
        \sum_{l = j}^{N}
        R_i \cdot R_j \cdot C_k \cdot C_l
$$

$$
    s^3:
        \sum_{i = 1}^{N - 1}
        \sum_{j = i + 1}^{N - 1}
        \sum_{k = j + 1}^{N}
        \sum_{l = i}^{j - 1}
        \sum_{m = j}^{k - 1}
        \sum_{n = k}^{N}
        R_i \cdot R_j \cdot R_k \cdot C_l \cdot C_m \cdot C_n
$$
$$
    s^4:
        \sum_{i = 1}^{N - 1}
        \sum_{j = i + 1}^{N - 1}
        \sum_{k = j + 1}^{N}
        \sum_{l = k + 1}^{N}
        \sum_{m = i}^{j - 1}
        \sum_{n = j}^{k - 1}
        \sum_{o = k}^{l - 1}
        \sum_{p = l}^{N}
        R_i \cdot R_j \cdot R_k \cdot R_l \cdot C_m \cdot C_n \cdot C_o \cdot C_p
$$

And so on. I think I've figured out the structure for $s^n$, as I tried this up sixth-order ($s^6$), which works out (I can check this against other representations).
What I would like to have is a form where the structure (number of summation symbols and R's and C's) does not change depending on the order of the coefficient:

$$s^i = ?$$

Are there standard techniques or some practical tips on how to tackle this?

Some background: I'm trying to derive a closed form of the transfer function of a cascaded RC-network (electronics). The equations describe the coefficients of the polynom in the denominator of the transfer function. Ultimately, I need to implement this in a program. As I can't hard-code the number of for-loops, I'm searching for a more suitable representation, perhaps also a representation that lends itself for a recursive implementation. Any guidance is welcome.